# steps marked with trigger: status = failure, always run, even if status is success

Tags: drone.io

I want to send notification in case any of the build step fails in drone ci. I tried adding following trigger at various levels, but it always runs, even in case of success.

Trigger that I am trying is as follows:

```
trigger:
  status:
  - failure
```

Tried setting it up inside/outside the steps. but it keeps getting triggered every time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `where` instead of `trigger`, like this:

```
  - name: notify-me
    image: ...

    ...

    when:
      status: [ failure ]
```

Comment: thanks for answer. but this "when" syntax works on older versions of drone. the trigger syntax is the newer one (1.0.x).